# It there a way to precisely match this text pattern with Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match only the text that starts with a hash (`#`) followed by words separated by hyphens (`-`).

Example text: `#stack-overflow-questions`

I've tried this, but it's not the best. Is there a way I can improve the Regex to be more precise?

```
const questionFormat = /^#(\w*-\w*)\1*/;
```

Comment: Try `/^#[\w-]+/`

Comment: try `/^#\w+-\w+(-\w+)*/`

Comment: `/^#\w+(-\w+)*$/`

Comment: @p.s.w.g That would allow a--b which appears invalid

Comment: @anubhava that allows `stack` which is invalid given a strict interpretation of the question

Comment: @JGNI: You can change last `*` to `+` if at least one hyphen is required in input

Comment: @JGNI The question isn't clear enough in my opinion to know exactly what's valid. It says nothing about the length of the words or how many words should be matched, whether the string can start with `#-` or end with `-` or if `--` is allowed in the middle. OP really should add more positive and negative test cases to the question.

Comment: @p.s.w.g fair enough. Regexes have to be precise, specifications rarely are :-)

Comment: Aww, some much support. Thank you, everyone. I really appreciate it!!! I tired out @JGNI and the $ and it's perfect what I need. Thanks again JGNI and everyone!!

Answer (score 2):

Probably look for `#` then one or more `\w+-` (zero or more if `#stack` is allowed) followed by one or more `\w`:

```
const rex = /#(?:\w+-)+\w+/;
```

Live Example:

```js
const rex = /#(?:\w+-)+\w+/;
console.log(rex.exec("blah blah #stack-overflow-questions blah blah")); // Finds it
console.log(rex.exec("blah blah #stack blah blah")); // null
```

Comment: This matches `#stack-overflow_questions` which probably isn't what OP wanted but since they didn't give enough to go off of I gave a +1 for the neat (and fast) regex

Comment: @chevybow - Fair point, although since they used `\w`, I sort of assumed `_` was okay... :-)

Answer (score 1):

The below should do the job.

```
^#[a-z\-]+
```

Comment: It should be because I used uppercase. Try 
`^#[a-z\-]+`

Comment: That would also match for example `#-----`

Answer (score 0):

```
  var str = "blah blah #stack-overflow-questions #stack-overflow-questiosss blah blah";
  var pat = /#[\w+-]{2,}/g;
  var result = str.match(pat);
```

found 2 matches

{2,} used to not catch only "-" but it still can catch "--"